# Jquery - Add new row to table (IE friendly version)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, html-table

Im' having problems with JQuery and Internet Explore (IE). My method for adding rows doesn't seem to be working in IE (Chrome & Firefox pose no problem)

Imagine following table

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td><button class="btn">btn1a</button></td>
        <td><button class="btn">btn1b</button></td>
        <td>zever</td>
        <td>zeverin pakskes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><button class="btn">btn2a</button></td>
        <td><button class="btn">btn2b</button></td>
        <td>zever</td>
        <td>zeverin pakskes</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

To Add rows (when the user clicks a 'button') i perform the following method

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn').on('click',function(){
        var parentrow = $(this).parent().parent();
        parentrow.after('<tr ><td colspan="4">Dit is een colspan rij</td></tr>');
    });
});
```

**Question:** How can i alter my method so it works in IE too? (e. g. the row is being added)?

**Note:** i'm using the following JQuery - library

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: hey all this question for a typo

Comment: @user3127499 Better an elaborate question for a typo, than a bad one!

Comment: @nietonfir yep but my experiences taught me other wise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the traling space in your opening `<tr>` tag, IE doesn't like invalid HTML (no joke!!). ;-)

```
parentrow.after('<tr><td colspan="4">Dit is een colspan rij</td></tr>');
```

Comment: Oh god! I think i'm gonna bang my head against the wall for some time :). Your solution was right. I wasn't aware that IE could act that difficult over a stupid spacing.

Answer (score 2):

I also came across the same problem few months back and followed the below approach

Create the elements as separate elements instead:

```
parent.after($('<tr/>').append($('<td colspan="4" />').text('Dit is een colspan rij')));
```

Comment: Nice piece of code there! :) Question: Instead of inserting plain text, could I insert Html aswell (using the .text())?

Comment: That doesn't work in older IE versions iirc. IE doesn't like self-closing elements during creation ironically.

Comment: Oh nice! I know just the function to test that!